# How to target The First Div Within a Series of Divs in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of Divs within another div and I want to only target the first one.

```
<div id="content">
  <div>
    I want to target this Div
  </div>

  <div>
  </div>

  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would I target only the first one and leave the rest alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this:

```
$('#content div').first()
```

Answer (score 1):

try `$('#content div:first')`.